# Getting cell values from the last 2 non-zero cells in a column in Excel

Tags: excel

I have a spreadsheet I use to track supplies inventory and estimate usages for ordering purposes. I’ll check all the inventory levels some days and maybe just one item on a certain day so I end up with a table that has a lot of blank cells. I’d like a formula that looks at the last 2 entries in a column and figures our the usage by subtracting the last 2 values and then dividing that number by the difference between the days when that item was counted. Here’s an example table:

[Example Table Here](http://cl.ly/image/1Q1u321p0f0A)

The end results I want are as follows:

- Usage for Box 1 - (120-99)/(Feb 10 - Jan 12) = .724 per day
- Usage for Box 2 - (70-50)/(Feb 10 - Jan 17) = .833 per day
- Usage for Tape - (156-100)/(Feb 2 - Jan 1) = 1.750 per day

Whenever I do an inventory for an item, I want the formula to always look at each column's latest two values and compute the daily usage. Thanks

Comment: Yes, I'll have to replenish so it won't allows be trending downwards. It would go up at that point of stocking up again

Answer (score 0):

If the trend is always downwards:

```
=(SMALL(B:B,2)-SMALL(B:B,1))/(INDEX($A:$A,MATCH(SMALL(B:B,1),B:B,0))-INDEX($A:$A,MATCH(SMALL(B:B,2),B:B,0)))
```

may suit, copied across.

Answer (score 0):

Or like this:

```
=(INDEX(B1:B6,MATCH(99^99,B1:INDEX(B1:B6,MATCH(99^99,B1:B6,1)-1,1)))-INDEX(B1:B6,MATCH(99^99,B1:B6,1)))/(INDEX($A$1:$A$6,MATCH(99^99,B1:B6,1))-INDEX($A$1:$A$6,MATCH(99^99,B1:INDEX(B1:B6,MATCH(99^99,B1:B6,1)-1,1))))
```

Comment: @pnuts oops. I missed replacing one of my helper cell references. Fixed now. Your's is more elegant, anyway.